# How to modify pod file to add configuration for react-native-permissions plugin in expo@49 app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, react-native-permissions

I had a React native cli app that I needed to convert into an expo app. The app was using the react-native-permission plugin for managing permission for multiple plugins. It requires changes in the Pod file and Android manifest file. In my expo-managed project, I don't know how to add this configuration.

How can I write a custom configuration that can update pod file and android manifest for react-native-permission plugin requirements?

https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#readme

I couldn't find much material on it. So any help will be much appreciated.